# Remote Desktop Printing

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, printing, network-printer

I use Remote Desktop with a VPN to my office. Sometimes I want to print documents created on the office machine to my remote location printer. The printer is a new Canon wireless unit. I checked the box in the Options window of RD to allow this feature to function to no avail.

Is there some other setting I should try to change?

Comment: Why don't you just transfer the file to your local machine and print it?  What you might not be possible using the software that you use.

Answer (score 0):

When you RDP in, it should detect the printer automatically. Next time you log in via RDP, go to event viewer and see if you get the 111 ID error.

In some cases, installing the driver on the remote machine for your canon (even though the canon can't communicate with your remote computer) can help.

Or, install a bogus printer which doesn't exist at all - the print will search local drives, find nothing, then search network drives, find nothing and use your default machine on your local computer (or it did back on XP).

I have also had issues where my AV (anti virus) stopped it coming through on the local machine.